# Error on jboss server on uploading image

Tags: java, jboss, out-of-memory

I am working on a java website. When I upload an image then I get the following server error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at sun.java2d.loops.GraphicsPrimitiveMgr.<clinit>(GraphicsPrimitiveMgr.java:38)
    at sun.java2d.loops.DrawLine.locate(DrawLine.java:37)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m 
    -XX:PermSize=128m 
    -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 

SET JAVA_OPTS=-Xrs -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
in run.bat file
```

Comment: where can i set this.

Comment: can you tell me in details??????

Comment: which version of jboss are you using??